# How to unbind ready-events >= jQuery 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, ready

As of jQuery v3.0 the recommended way to bind DOM-ready-methods is `$( myReadyFunction )` without any selector or delegation. Especially `$(document).on('ready', myReadyFunction )` is removed in jQuery v3.

I now need to modify/override a specific, pre-existing ready-method before it is executed. I know that I can delay the execution of the ready-event by calling `$.holdReady( true )` ... but how can I remove/override my old `myReadyFunction` ?

---

Existing code that should not be changed:

`myReadyFunction = function() { console.info('old'); }
$( myReadyFunction );`

I can add code before or after this part, here are some things I tried and did not work:

---

adding after

`$.off( 'myReadyFunction' );`

=> $.off is not a function

---

adding after

`$(document).off( 'myReadyFunction' );
$(document).off( 'ready', 'myReadyFunction' );`

=> no error messsage, but both variants don't work

---

`myReadyFunction = function() { console.info('new'); }
$( myReadyFunction );`

=> adds the new, overridden function, but does not remove the old one

Comment: The DOM Ready handling is no longer treated as an event, but as [a `Deffered` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) ([this is where the registration happens](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js#L10)). You can access the "thenable" directly, [with `jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ready/). Your question therefore boils down to "Can I remove a callback from a jQuery Deferred object / thenable?"

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve? In other words, what is your use case?

Comment: The context is a CMS (Drupal), which uses themes and sub-/child-themes. The parent theme has multiple ready functions, and I need to modify one. I want to avoid altering the parent theme's code, but I also want to keep all the other functionality provided by the parent theme's JS file.